# Replacing av_read_frame() to reduce delay

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, delay, latency

I am implementing a (very) low latency video streaming C++ application using ffmpeg. The client receives a video which is encoded with x264’s zerolatency preset, so there is no need for buffering. As described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3354), if you use *av_read_frame*() to read packets of the encoded video stream, you will always have at least one frame delay because of internal buffering done in ffmpeg. So when I call *av_read_frame*() after frame n+1 has been sent to the client, the function will return frame n.

Getting rid of this buffering by setting the AVFormatContext flags AVFMT_FLAG_NOPARSE | AVFMT_FLAG_NOFILLIN as suggested in the [source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3354) disables packet parsing and therefore breaks decoding, as noted in the [source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3354).

Therefore, I am writing my own packet receiver and parser. First, here are the relevant steps of the working solution (including one frame delay) using *av_read_frame*():

```
AVFormatContext *fctx;
AVCodecContext *cctx;
AVPacket *pkt;
AVFrame *frm;

//Initialization of AV structures
//…

//Main Loop
while(true){

    //Receive packet
    av_read_frame(fctx, pkt);

    //Decode:
    avcodec_send_packet(cctx, pkt);
    avcodec_receive_frame(cctx, frm);

    //Display frame
    //…
}
```

And below is my solution, which mimics the behavior of *av_read_frame*(), as far as I could reproduce it. I was able to track the source code of [*av_read_frame*](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html#l01767)() down to [*ff_read_packet*](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html#l00831)(),but  I cannot find the source of [*AVInputformat.read_packet*](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avformat_8h_source.html#l00714)().

```
int tcpsocket;
AVCodecContext *cctx;
AVPacket *pkt;
AVFrame *frm;
uint8_t recvbuf[(int)10e5];
memset(recvbuf,0,10e5);
int pos = 0;

AVCodecParserContext * parser = av_parser_init(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
parser->flags |= PARSER_FLAG_COMPLETE_FRAMES;
parser->flags |= PARSER_FLAG_USE_CODEC_TS;

//Initialization of AV structures and the tcpsocket
//…

//Main Loop
while(true){

    //Receive packet
    int length = read(tcpsocket, recvbuf, 10e5);
    if (length >= 0) {

        //Creating temporary packet
        AVPacket * tempPacket = new AVPacket;
        av_init_packet(tempPacket);
        av_new_packet(tempPacket, length);
        memcpy(tempPacket->data, recvbuf, length);
        tempPacket->pos = pos;
        pos += length;
        memset(recvbuf,0,length);

        //Parsing temporary packet into pkt
        av_init_packet(pkt);
        av_parser_parse2(parser, cctx,
            &(pkt->data), &(pkt->size),
            tempPacket->data, tempPacket->size,
            tempPacket->pts, tempPacket->dts, tempPacket->pos
            );

        pkt->pts = parser->pts;
        pkt->dts = parser->dts;
        pkt->pos = parser->pos;

        //Set keyframe flag
        if (parser->key_frame == 1 ||
            (parser->key_frame == -1 &&
            parser->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I))
            pkt->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        if (parser->key_frame == -1 && parser->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE && (pkt->flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY))
            pkt->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        pkt->duration = 96000; //Same result as in av_read_frame()

        //Decode:
        avcodec_send_packet(cctx, pkt);
        avcodec_receive_frame(cctx, frm);
        //Display frame
        //…
    }
}
```

I checked the [fields](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVPacket.html) of the resulting packet (*pkt*) just before *avcodec_send_packet*() in both solutions. They are as far as I can tell identical. The only difference might be the actual content of *pkt->data*. My solution decodes I-Frames fine, but the references in P-Frames seem to be broken, causing heavy artifacts and error messages such as “invalid level prefix”, “error while decoding MB xx”, and similar.

I would be very grateful for any hints.

**Edit 1:** I have developed a workaround for the time being: in the video server, after sending the packet containing the encoded data of a frame, I send one dummy packet which only contains the delimiters marking beginning and end of the packet. This way, I push the actual video data frames through *av_read_frame*(). I discard the dummy packets immediately after *av_frame_read*().

**Edit 2:** Solved [here](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/pull/646) by rom1v, as written in his comment to this question.

Comment: As for `AVInputformat.read_packet()` this function pointer will be set for corresponding codec's `read_packet()` function, easiest way to confirm is compiling FFmpeg with debug info (easiest way to me just before 'make' edit ffbuild/config.mak file, find 'STRIP=strip' and replace it as 'STRIP=echo', than make and make install.). Later run your code with breakpoint set the function you want, after breakpoint hit, use bt (backtrace) on gdb. And also I notice you used `av_init_packet` and `av_new_packet` together, but `av_new_packet` also calls `av_init_packet` so you don't need it.

Comment: I encouter the very same problem, `av_read_frame()` introduce 1 frame latency: it calls (and blocks on) my custom `avio_ctx->read_packet` to receive more data while it has not consumed the previous (complete) packet. What data do you write exactly for your "dummy packet"?

Comment: Assume that I encoded an image with `x264_encoder_encode(enc_ctx, &nals, &num_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);`. The compressed data is in `nals`. Then, after sending the full frame (e.g. `for(int i=0;i<num_nals;++i){ write(newfd, nals[i].p_payload, nals[i].i_payload); }`) I write 50 Bytes of the beginning and end of the frame: `write(sock, nals[0].p_payload, 50); write(sock, nals[num_nals - 1].p_payload + nals[num_nals -1].i_payload - 50, 50);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your original post, the problem is that if you set `PARSER_FLAG_COMPLETE_FRAMES`, then you are responsible to only pass complete frames to `av_parser_parse2` (and if you unset the flag, you will still get 1 frame latency). I finally managed to parse manually and reduce the latency by 1 frame: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/pull/646

Comment: Good point. For me, it worked as described in my previous answer. Thank you for sharing your solution, excellent work!

Comment: I'm running on the same issue while trying to achieve low-latency streaming. The problem is that I can't modify the server side. Is there a possibility to remove the 1-frame latency from the av_read_frame in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*av_parser_parse2*() does not neccessarily consume your *tempPacket* in one go.  You have to call it in another loop and check its return value, like in the [API docs](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavc__parsing.html#ga691ca0258e91f99297e7726f56d8c247).